# debug python code inside docker container without rebuild

Tags: python, docker, debugging

I would like to be able to debug python code with for instance pdb or pudb without the need to set breakpoints (`set_trace`) and thus the need to rebuild a docker imager.

Pycharm does the job "like a charm", but I'd like to stick to other editors and rely on tools like pdb, pudb, etc.

Any input is more then welcome.

Thanks

PS: yes, I'm aware of the telnet connection to a pdb breakpoint, but in order to set (or change) the breakpoint I have to rebuild the package.

Answer (score 0):

By mapping the volume where my code is located between the host and the docker file, I can set breakpoints without the need to re-build the image.

Together with `pudb.remote` this works like charm. Pudb remote explained for example [here](https://www.stolarscy.com/dryobates/2016-09/debugging_gunicorn_on_docker_with_pudb/).